# how to match gene probe ID with gene symbol in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, glmnet

I have a dataframe with genes and samples (cancer vs. normal) and I already did LASSO and cross validation to choose best lambda, as well as finding the genes with non-zero coefficients (x in code below is my dataframe containing these). What I want to do next is add another column to x which contains the gene symbols (symbol from original dataframe daf) corresponding to those gene with non-zero coefficients in x. I have been trying for over an hour now to get that to work but haven't had success. Any suggestions on what is the best way to do that? Below is my code:

```
probeID<-c("213456_at", "217428_s_at", "219230_at", "226228_at","230030_at")
symbol<-c("SOSTDC1","COL10A1", "TMEM100", "AQP4", "HS6ST2")

BCR1<-c(28.005966, 30.806433, 17.341375, 17.40666, 30.039436)
BCR2<-c(30.973469, 29.236025, 30.41161, 20.914383, 20.904331)
BCR3<-c(26.322796, 25.542833, 22.460772, 19.972183, 30.409641)
BCR4<-c(26.441898, 25.837685, 23.158352, 20.379173, 33.81327)
BCR5<-c(39.750206, 19.901133, 28.180124, 22.668673, 25.748884)
CTL6<-c(23.004385, 28.472675, 23.81621, 26.433413, 28.851719)
CTL7<-c(22.239546, 28.741674, 23.754929, 26.015385, 28.16368)
CTL8<-c(29.590443, 30.041988, 21.323061, 24.272501, 18.099016)
CTL9<-c(15.856442, 22.64224, 29.629637, 25.374926, 22.356894)
CTL10<-c(38.137985, 24.753338, 26.986668, 24.578161, 19.223558)
daf<-data.frame(probeID, symbol, BCR1, BCR2, BCR3, BCR4, BCR5, CTL6, CTL7, CTL8, CTL9, CTL10)

daf1<-t(daf[,3:12])
colnames(daf1)<-daf$probeID
View(daf1)

Type<-c("cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "cancer", "normal", "normal", "normal", "normal", "normal")
Sample<-c("BCR1", "BCR2", "BCR3", "BCR4", "BCR5", "CTL6", "CTL7", "CTL8", "CTL9", "CTL10")
type.df<-data.frame(Sample, Type)

daf2<-data.frame(daf1, type.df$Type)
names(daf2)[names(daf2) == "type.df.Type"] <- "Type"
View(daf2)
daf2$Type<-as.factor(daf2$Type)

lassoModel <- glmnet(
  x=data.matrix(daf2[,-6]),
  y=daf2$Type,
  alpha=1,
  family="binomial")
plot(lassoModel, xvar="lambda")
coef(lassoModel)[,5][coef(lassoModel)[,5]!=0]

#Cross Validation
cv.lassoModel<- cv.glmnet(
  x=data.matrix(daf2[,-6]),
  y=daf2$Type,
  alpha=1, family="binomial")

# plot variable deviances vs. shrinkage parameter, λ (lambda)
plot(cv.lassoModel)

#Chose best lambda
idealLambda <- cv.lassoModel$lambda.min
idealLambda1se <- cv.lassoModel$lambda.1se
print(idealLambda); print(idealLambda1se)

# derive coefficients for each gene
co <- coef(cv.lassoModel, s=idealLambda, exact=TRUE)
co

co.se <- coef(cv.lassoModel, s=idealLambda1se, exact=TRUE)
co.se

#Select those genes that have non-zero coefficients for the best lambda
cv.glm.probe<-coef(cv.lassoModel, s="lambda.min")
x<-data.frame(cv.glm.probe[cv.glm.probe[,1]!=0,])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at your coefficients, they have an extra "X" in front, because glm, lm, glmnet etc does not like variables that start with a number, and by default adds an "X".

```
x$symbol = daf$symbol[match(sub("^X","",rownames(x)),daf$probeID)]
x

             cv.glm.probe.cv.glm.probe...1.....0...  symbol
(Intercept)                            -41.23471919    <NA>
X217428_s_at                             0.18134947 COL10A1
X226228_at                               1.61933359    AQP4
X230030_at                              -0.03797544  HS6ST2
```

If you have say a data.frame where the X doesn't exist, for example:

```
df = data.frame(coefficients=runif(5))
rownames(df) = sample(daf$probeID,5)
df$symbol = daf$symbol[match(rownames(df),daf$probeID)]
```

Or have the actual probe in a data frame and merge:

```
df = data.frame(probe=sample(daf$probeID,5),coefficients=runif(5))
merge(df,daf[,c("probeID","symbol")],by.x="probe",by.y="probeID")

        probe coefficients  symbol
1   213456_at   0.40697051 SOSTDC1
2 217428_s_at   0.97655456 COL10A1
3   219230_at   0.09496977 TMEM100
4   226228_at   0.70865375    AQP4
5   230030_at   0.35125967  HS6ST2
```

Comment: Oh, that's perfect, thank you! Just out of curiosity, what options would I have had to do this if I did not have that "X" in front of the gene names? Or if for example, instead of the gene names with the "X", I had the symbols and was trying to match the symbols with the respective gene names?

Comment: Ok i have edited the answer, two ways to merge the data.. Hope it's what you need

Comment: fyi, the function that produces the X at the start is `make.names` so rather than using substitution, you could use `make.names` before running glmnet to ensure you have exactly matching IDs.

Comment: Hi @alanocallaghan, thanks for pointing it out. I don't know about make.names that runs underneath.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is very helpful!